# Animated Drop Down Menu for a Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, menu

I have never used jQuery before and I'm trying to do something really simple but it's been driving me crazy.
I have designed a template for a CMS and now I want to get its menus animated.
The picture below explains the structure of the menu (which is obviously generated by the CMS)
[image: The menu structure]

The code below is what I think should work, but it doesn't:

```
var menuItem = jQuery(".menu:first>li");
var subMenu;
for(var i=0; i<menuItem.length;i++)
{
    var li = jQuery(menuItem[i]);
    subMenu = li.children("ul");
    if (subMenu.length)
        li.hover(function(){ li.children("ul").slideToggle(250); });   
}
```

Basically, what I'm doing is get the first level `li`s and then add a `hover` listener to them, telling them to animate their child `ul` (which is the actual sub menu).
What I get instead is when I point to "Products" it's own sub menu does not show, instead, the sub menu for "Contact Us" pops up! When I point to "Contact Us" its sub menu pops up like it is supposed to. **Note:** The brown `ul` is set to display:none
I appreciate any help.
Thank in advance
**PS:** I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 (if it matters)

Comment: Also if anyone could suggest an alternative way, I would hugely appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks quite complicated for what your trying to achieve. i would do something like this.

```
$(".menu > li").hover(

  //When mouse is over the menu button
  function () {
    $(this).children("ul").slideDown(250);
  },

  //When mouse leaves the menu / menu button 
  function () {
    $(this).children("ul").slideUp(250);
  }
);
```

Comment: Damn! I just found that myself! Thanks for your answer. Really appreciate it. Why doesn't my code work anyway?!

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're trying to do in your code but I think you should start with good jQuery practices first. It's really not hard, you'll see. And it will make your life a lot easier.

First of all, I'm not sure a loop is what you want here. jQuery offers a selector (which can be used with $ as a shortcut) to select classes and it's really powerful.
Build your menu like this (sort of):

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li class="menu-item">Home
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">Products
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item">Contact us
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can select the menu items with

```
$('.menu-item')
```

and in its hover function, select the drop down with

```
$(this).childen('ul')
```

Then basically have fun!